# WordPress default functionality disturbed when I add a custom plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, vue.js, wp-enqueue-scripts

I have made a plugin on Vue which I am enqueuing on WordPress in the admin dashboard and frontend.

The plugin appears fine, but when I try to add a new page it displays a blank page.

When I disable the plugin, it is back to normal.

This is my code for the plugin enqueue.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Verus Vue Plugin
Description: This plugin adds an admin dashboard view.
Version: 1.0
Author: Ahmed Shah
*/

function my_admin_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Verus Data',  // Page title
        'Staking Rewards', // Menu title
        'manage_options',  // Capability required to access
        'my-admin-page',   // Menu slug
        'render_content', // Callback function to render content
        'dashicons-admin-plugins', // Icon URL or dashicon class
        20 // Menu position
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu_page');


function render_content() {
    ?>
        <h1>Verus Blocks</h1>
        <div id="app">
        </div>
<?php
}

function render_shortcode() {
    ?>
        <h1>Verus Blocks</h1>
        <div id="app">
        </div>
<?php
}

add_shortcode('vue_shortcode', 'render_shortcode');


function admin_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script('app-script', plugins_url('/verusapi/dist/assets/index-da85dad1.js', __FILE__), array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('app-style', plugins_url('/verusapi/dist/assets/index-37970cf5.css', __FILE__));
}

function enqueue_vue_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script('app-script', plugins_url('/verusapi/dist/assets/index-da85dad1.js', __FILE__), array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('app-style', plugins_url('/verusapi/dist/assets/index-37970cf5.css', __FILE__));
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_enqueue');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_vue_script');
```

I get the following error in browser console:

```
index.php:773 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at index.php:773:11
    at index.php:781:4
load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.3.1:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://veruswp.sink.cakeshop.dev/wp-admin/js/site-health.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2:36)
    at e (https://veruswp.sink.cakeshop.dev/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.3.1:2:26990)
    at t (https://veruswp.sink.cakeshop.dev/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.3.1:2:27292) undefined
ce.Deferred.exceptionHook @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.3.1:2
load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.3.1:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dateI18n') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dateI18n')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://veruswp.sink.cakeshop.dev/wp-admin/js/dashboard.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2:2984)
    at e (https://veruswp.sink.cakeshop.dev/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.3.1:2:26990)
    at t (https://veruswp.sink.cakeshop.dev/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.3.1:2:27292) undefined
ce.Deferred.exceptionHook @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.3.1:2
load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=6.3.1:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://veruswp.sink.cakeshop.dev/wp-admin/js/svg-painter.js?ver=6.3.1:19:18)
```

I also get this when I try to click Add New Page in WordPress admin dashboard:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://veruswp.sink.cakeshop.dev/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://0.0.0.20/'. This request was not upgraded to HTTPS because its URL's host is an IP address.
```

Comment: Enable WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG and look to the debug log. Note that on admin side, your JS (and CSS) should only load on your plugin screen(s).

Comment: How would my J's and css should do that?

Comment: @artistAhmed
You have ?page=my-admin-page GET param, that you can check in enqueue_vue_script before you enqueue. 

Also, if you do not make this build in separate class, use some unique prefix for functions name, to avoid conflicts with other plugins. 

To be able to provide real help, we need to see PHP error you have (blank page indicates that):
https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Or at least code that cause it (you mention that it's stop working when you add second page, but there is no code for second page in what you show us).

Comment: You need to make a function for `wp_enqueue_scripts`and another one for `admin_enqueue_scripts` where you will target your plugin admin pages only like in [this related answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632817/im-getting-bad-request-using-ajax-in-custom-wordpress-plugin/76638012#76638012)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec done that doesn't work check my updated code

Comment: @mWin I didn't understand where do I have that GET param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code, renaming function names and slugs, and adding the necessary code to the function hooked in `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook. Try instead:

```php
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Verus Vue Plugin
Description: This plugin adds an admin dashboard view.
Version: 1.0
Author: Ahmed Shah
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

function verus_vue_admin_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        __('Verus Data'),  // Page title
        __('Staking Rewards'), // Menu title
        'manage_options',  // Capability required to access
        'verus-vue',   // Menu slug
        'verus_vue_render_content', // Callback function to render content
        'dashicons-admin-plugins', // Icon URL or dashicon class
        20 // Menu position
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'verus_vue_admin_menu_page');

function verus_vue_render_content() {
    ?>
    <h1><?php _e('Verus Blocks'); ?></h1>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_shortcode('verus-vue', 'verus_vue_render_content'); // Short code usage: [verus-vue]


function admin_enqueue_vue_scripts( $hook ) {
    if ( 'toplevel_page_verus-vue' === $hook ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('app-script', plugins_url('/verusapi/dist/assets/index-da85dad1.js', __FILE__), array(), null, true);
        wp_enqueue_style('app-style', plugins_url('/verusapi/dist/assets/index-37970cf5.css', __FILE__));

        error_log($hook); // For testing (to be removed)
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_enqueue_vue_scripts');

function front_enqueue_vue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('app-script', plugins_url('/verusapi/dist/assets/index-da85dad1.js', __FILE__), array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('app-style', plugins_url('/verusapi/dist/assets/index-37970cf5.css', __FILE__));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'front_enqueue_vue_scripts');
```

It should better work now on admin side, as your scripts will only be loaded on your plugin page. I have merged the shortcode function and the callback menu function to render content, as they have the same code. I have renamed your shortcode to more explicit `[verus-vue]`.

Related: [I'm getting "Bad request" using ajax in custom WordPress plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632817/im-getting-bad-request-using-ajax-in-custom-wordpress-plugin/76638012#76638012)

Comment: Thank you works like a charm. I do still get a warning in console and an error but at least I can add new pages and don't get blank screens

Comment: Here we solved one important issue… Now you need to debug step by step... Then you can always ask a new question, providing the related code and explaining the issue you are facing.